# @Autowire does not work. Could not autowire, multiple bean with same name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create spring project in intellij. I have following interface:

**DAO**

```
    public interface DAO<T> {

    public int create(T object);
    public T read(int id);
    public int update(int id, T object);
    public int delete(int id);
    }
```

I have two other classes, Employee and Customer that implements this interface with @Repository annotation on them.

When I try to @Autowire the DAO interface in my controller class, IntelliJ shows compile time error "could not autowire, multiple bean of DAO type found".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the `@Autowired` on property it will use the autowire [byType](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/08/spring-beans-autowiring-concepts/) to resolve the collaborating bean. So in the case as you've described it will produce a conflict of more than one qualifying bean.

To resolve this, you should use [@Qualifier](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation, and add name to your  `@Repostiory` annotation, something like

```
class YourController
{
      @Qualifier("customer")
      @Autowired    
      private Dao customerRepository;
}


@Repository("customer")
class Customer implements Dao{}

@Repository("employee")
class Employee implements Dao{}
```